# problem with align

Tags: align

i'm trying to typeset someting like this:

```
\begin{align} f_{**p}(X_p,Y_p)  = X_p(Y(f)) = \sum_{i,j = 1} ^n \alpha_i
\beta_j E_{pi}(E_j(f)) f
\end{align}
short remark
\begin{align}
E_{pi}(E_j(f)) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(E_j(f) \circ \phi^{-1} )|_{\phi(p)} \\ 
               &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} ...
\end{align}
```

but I would like to put the short remark in a `\shortintertext` inside the same align environment, that is:

```
\begin{align} f_{**p}(X_p,Y_p)  = X_p(Y(f)) = \sum_{i,j = 1} ^n \alpha_i
\beta_j E_{pi}(E_j(f)) f
\shortintertext{short remark}
E_{pi}(E_j(f)) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(E_j(f) \circ \phi^{-1} )|_{\phi(p)} \\ 
               &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} ...
\end{align}
```

However for some reason the spacing is terrible in this last one. How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is a comment not directly related to the core of your question, but to your apparent usage of summation notation: The expression `\sum_{i,j = 1} ^n` is potentially ambiguous as it could be taken to indicate that the indices `i` and `j` should always be equal, i.e., `i=j=1`, `i=j=2`, ..., `i=j=n`. If that's *not* what you want to express, i.e., if the indices `i` and `j` can range independently from `1` to `n`, it may be preferable to use double summation notation: `\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the first equation to align with the others, use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  f_{**p}(X_p,Y_p)  = X_p(Y(f)) = \sum_{i,j = 1} ^n \alpha_i
\beta_j E_{pi}(E_j(f)) f
\\
\shortintertext{short remark}
\begin{align}
  E_{pi}(E_j(f)) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(E_j(f) \circ \phi^{-1} )|_{\phi(p)} \\
               &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
\end{align}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know you could use one environment inside the other. Accepted!

Comment: @Emilio This works as long as you don't label the equations inside align, see also my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85699/21591.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to nest an `align` environment inside a `gather` environment. Why not just use an `equation` environment for the first equation and a *non-nested* `align` environment for the second and third equations? A side benefit of such a setup is that it won't cause trouble with missed page breaks; by default, the `gather` environment doesn't allow page breaks between equations...

Comment: @Mico All true. But the OP asked specifically for that to get the narrow spacing with `\shortintertext`. I myself would probably try an `equation` together with an `align`, maybe accompanied with `\SwapAboveDisplaySkip`. But that might be another answer ... ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You missed a `&` in the first equation and a `\\` before `\shortintertext{short remark}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
f_{**p}(X_p,Y_p)  &= X_p(Y(f)) = \sum_{i,j = 1} ^n \alpha_i
\beta_j E_{pi}(E_j(f)) f\\
\shortintertext{short remark}
E_{pi}(E_j(f)) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(E_j(f) \circ \phi^{-1} )|_{\phi(p)} \\ 
               &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## On request from Op:

You can use `\span\omit` as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
f_{**p}(X_p,Y_p)  = X_p(Y(f)) = \sum_{i,j = 1} ^n \alpha_i
\beta_j E_{pi}(E_j(f)) f
\end{equation}
\begin{align} 
 f_{**p}(X_p,Y_p)  = X_p(Y(f)) = \sum_{i,j = 1} ^n \alpha_i
\beta_j E_{pi}(E_j(f)) f \span\omit\\
\shortintertext{short remark}
E_{pi}(E_j(f)) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(E_j(f) \circ \phi^{-1} )|_{\phi(p)} \\ 
               &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The point, however, is that I don't want the part after the short remark to be aligned with anything above. I would like the first line to have its own natural spacing and would like to start aligning stuff after that, which is what happens if I use two separate align environments.

Comment: Do you want to align things from second equation onwards? If so, put first equation inside `\begin{equation}` and rest inside align.

Comment: But I wanted to put my short remark in a shortintertext to avoid losing a lot of space. Perhaps there is no way to avoid alignign equations starting from the first line in the align environment...

Comment: @Emilio See the update. I have changed and added the `&` in first equation. Let me know if it is ok. The first equation is for showing that the natural position is matching.

Comment: But now the aligned equations aren't centered as they were before.

Comment: @Emilio True. That is I wrote that `gather` is better.