# Aligned multline

Tags: amsmath, align, multline

I want to show the derivation of a formula where I encounter long formulae. Unfortunately the derivation is very complex, so I have to show some intermediate steps.

My problem is, that I want to mix the behaviour of multline with align. The first line should be aligned left and the whole rest should be aligned right with respect to the longest line. This block should be aligned at the `=`.

At the moment, I use the `align` environment. But in this case, the first line is still aligned left to the `$` of the other lines.

Important note: I don't like magic numbers. So I prefer solutions which are completely automatic.

---

My approach so far:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% Kodierung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% Sprache (neue deutsche Rechtschreibung)
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% Mathematik
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        (a+b+c+d+e+f) \\ % aligned left
        % the following block should be aligned right
        &= a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n\\
    \begin{split}
        &= a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n \\
        & \quad +o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z+1+2+3+4
    \end{split}\\
        &= a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84345/21591

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what I would do (require `mathtools` package)

```
\begin{align}
   \MoveEqLeft[3]  (a+b+c+d+e+f) \\ 
    ={}& a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n\\
\begin{split}
    ={}& a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n \\
    &  +o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z+1+2+3+4
\end{split}\\
    ={}& a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p
\end{align}
```

I would not want to start using `multline` effects in it, ends up looking strange. The above sort of follows the guides set out by the AMS.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a version without magic numbers. It uses the `mathtools` to make the first line appear to have zero width.

```
\begin{align}
    \mathclap{(a+b+c+d+e+f)} & \notag \\
    &= a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n \\
    &= a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n \notag \\
    & \quad +o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z+1+2+3+4 \\
    &= a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p
\end{align}
```

[image: with mathclap]

Comment: Which gives you problems, if the lines are long, then the first line goes into the left margin. The magic number is not that magic, it is the number of ems to move the first line backwards. Plus it follows the MAS recommendstion about the indentation from the left

Comment: I have to admit, that your answer is the best according to my question for shorter equations like daleif noted. I meant magic numbers like [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64998/spacing-of-multline-inside-align-i-e-multlined) where the length of the environment is given by the user.

Comment: I would not use that constrction either. The only reason why I use a number here is because I align to the right of the `=`. The default is `2`, as recommended by AMS

Comment: @daleif I removed the `3` and aligned to the left of the `=` to follow the recommendation.

Comment: Then you have to add the `\quad` which is cumbersome (I have macros in my editor to do `&= -> = {} &` so I save some time). Besides, aligning to the right is not as often as aligning to the left.

Comment: @daleif I advertised the usage of `\MoveEqLeft` on tx.sx myself, TYVM. I just wanted to show a version that works for the MWE at hand, and follows Stefans expressed dislike of magic numbers. Your 3em have to be adapted by hand, e.g., when the RHS increase, you need 4em etc, so it is a magic number.