# How to align the equations to start from left

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

```
 \begin{align*}

(pq+p-3)^2-(3pq+p+q-6)(pq+p-3)+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)\\

=(p^2q^2+p^2+9+2p^2q-6q-6pq)-(3p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-6pq+3p^6q+p^2+pq-6p-9pq-3p-3q+18)+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)\\

=pq^2-6pq+5p+5q-5\\

=pq(q-6)+5(p+q-1)

\end{align*}
```

I ran the above code in LaTeX but unfortunately the output is not coming well. The same happens when I use `gather*` environment.

I am attaching the screenshot for this.

I want all the "=" signs to start from left.
Also I want to start each line starting with "=" from a new line which is not happening in this code.

Further I dont want each line starting with "=" to come up with a new equation number but all these are happening.

Kindly suggest me some remedies for this.

Please find the output attached.

[image]

In other words my calculation looks very worse in my paper.How to align or make it look good ?

Comment: Why do you use `align*` inside `gather*`?

Comment: @JouleV;they both are producing same thing,both are having difficulty with the things I mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal, based on suggestions from [this question's answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98347/156344) (package `geometry` added to have a nice-looking margin):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\;(pq+p-3)^2-(3pq+p+q-6)(pq+p-3)+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)\\
=&\;(p^2q^2+p^2+9+2p^2q-6q-6pq)-(3p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-6pq+3p^6q+p^2+\\
&\quad+pq-6p-9pq-3p-3q+18)+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)\\
=&\;pq^2-6pq+5p+5q-5\\
=&\;pq(q-6)+5(p+q-1)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't add blank lines anywhere you want, unless you know what they are doing. For example, adding a single blank line inside `align*` in the above example can cause compilation error.

Comment: What does the command &\; do ?Is this the one which helps us to achieve it

Comment: @Learnmore `&` is a special character, its role in `align` can be found in the [`amsmath` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf). `\;` is for the seperation space between "=" and the right hand side.

Comment: Thank you very much but I have another doubt. I used your code in another set of equations but it failed,here is the code.

Comment: \begin{align*}
(pq+q-3)^2-(3pq+p+q-6)(pq+q-3)+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)\\
=&\;(p^2q^2+q^2+9+2pq^2-6q-6pq)
+(-3p^2q^2-p^2q-pq^2+6pq-3pq^2-pq-q^2+6q+9pq+3p+3q-18)\\+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)\\
=&\;p^2q-5-6pq+5p+5q\\
=&\;pq(p-6)+5(p+q-1)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: What should I do now?Can you kindly help

Comment: @Learnmore You forgot `&` (and `\quad` or `\;` or `\qquad` etc.) on the first line and the fourth line. To prevent margin exceeding, I think you should find another line-break point.