# How to align the lines on the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, line

Consider the code

```
\begin{align*}

(pq+q-3)^2-(3pq+p+q-6)(pq+q-3)+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)\\
=&\;(p^2q^2+q^2+9+2pq^2-6q-6pq)

+(-3p^2q^2-p^2q-pq^2+6pq-3pq^2-pq-q^2+6q+9pq+3p+3q-18)\\+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)\\

=&\;p^2q-5-6pq+5p+5q\\

=&\;pq(p-6)+5(p+q-1)\\
\end{align*}
```

I used the technique which was shown here [How to align the equations to start from left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482694/184856)

but I it is not working here.

The lines are getting disbalanced.Can someone help please

Comment: your equation are to long that can be fit in text width,  can be broken into more lines?

Comment: `align` is designed to provide the correct spacing after operators when the `&` is placed before them.  Moving the `&` would get rid of the need to explicitly add space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: remove all blank lines inside `align*`.

Some of your lines don't have `&`, which causes the equation to be unbalanced.

Fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
&\;(pq+q-3)^2-(3pq+p+q-6)(pq+q-3)+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)\\ =&\;(p^2q^2+q^2+9+2pq^2-6q-6pq)+(-3p^2q^2-p^2q-pq^2+6pq-3pq^2-pq-q^2+6q\\
&\quad+9pq+3p+3q-18)+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)\\ 
=&\;p^2q-5-6pq+5p+5q\\ 
=&\;pq(p-6)+5(p+q-1)\\ 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To avoid margin exceeding, consider adding `\usepackage{geometry}` or change the line-breaking points.

Comment: Yes,how does the package geometry help and how to use it,if i use it will it automatically align the lines to the left

Comment: @Learnmore [`article`'s default margin is very big and IMHO ugly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71172/156344), and `geometry` can make the margin much nicer. You can even control the margin using this package. For more information read [the package documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf).

Comment: How should i use it,will writing \usepackage{geometry} take care of all4

Comment: @Learnmore It only takes care of the margin. You can set your own margin by `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` or `\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm]{geometry}`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

with use of the macro `\MoveEqLeft` from the package `mathtools` and correct placing of ampersands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft
(pq+q-3)^2-(3pq+p+q-6)(pq+q-3)+2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)    \\
& = (p^2q^2+q^2+9+2pq^2-6q-6pq)                                 \\
&\quad +(-3p^2q^2-p^2q-pq^2+6pq-3pq^2-pq-q^2+6q+9pq+3p+3q-18)   \\
&\quad +2(p^2q^2+p^2q+pq^2-7pq+p+q+2)                           \\
& = p^2q-5-6pq+5p+5q                                            \\
& =  pq(p-6)+5(p+q-1)
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

[image]