# Multiple labels error in align inside gather

Tags: cross-referencing, align, gather

I have written the following piece of latex (ignore the formulas, don't make sense)

```latex
\begin{gather}
    \min \quad \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i b_i, \nonumber \\
    \begin{align}
        \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \geq i&,   & \forall i &= 1, \ldots, m, \label{eqn1} \\ 
        \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i} \geq i&,   & \forall i &= 1, \ldots, m, \label{eqn2} \\ 
        a_{ij}          \in \{0,1\}&,   & \forall i &= 1, \ldots, n, \; \forall j = 1, \ldots, n \nonumber
    \end{align}
\end{gather}
```

and I get the error: `! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eqn1' will be lost`.

From what I have found online this happens when more than one labels refers to the same equation, but I don't know how to solve it.

P.S., side questions: what's the best way to align the stuff inside the `align` block?

[This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412261/82917) does not work in my case: I need to `\label` two lines/equations inside the inner `align` environment, whereas the linked answer works only if you have one label inside the `align` environment and the other one outside.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412261/82917. I thought it had been corrected, but apparently not. It might be worth raising an issue with the maintenance team.

Comment: Unfortunately that solution does not work in my case: I need to label two lines/equations *inside* the align environment (whereas the linked answer works only if you have one label inside the align environment and the other one outside, just tried).

Comment: @campa: also, if you closed this question, please reopen it since this one is not solved by the other you linked.

Comment: I didn't close the question and I posted only a comment without marking it as duplicate. This being said, I voted to reopen, as I can confirm that the issue persists, but please edit your question explaining that the solution in the linked question does not work.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `\[ … \]` for the first equation, followed by an independent `align` environment?

Comment: @Bernard: yes, at the moment that's my workaround, but in that way I have to manually fix the space between the two environment.

Comment: Did try the `\useshortskip`  command from `nccmath`,   before `align` ?