# Tagging Each Line in `aligned`

Tags: align, alignment, empheq, gather

I want to combine the `gather` and `aligned` environments in the following way.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    A = B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I \\
\begin{aligned}
    X &\le 2 \\
    Y &\le 123
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
A = B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I \\
\begin{aligned}
    X &\le 2 \\
    Y &\le 123123
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image: dark mode pdf]

However, I want to be able to label the two lines `X \le 2` and `Y \le 123` individually. If it were just those two, I'd simply use `align`, not `aligned` inside `gather`. But, I want there to be this separate first line, which may be of incomparable length and also has a number. The `aligned` section should be centred with respect to that first line. This centring can be seen by comparing (1, 2) with (3, 4).

I have seen people use the `empheq` package. However, it *seems* that `\begin{empheq}` can only be started outside of maths mode. So, I'm not really sure how to use that.

I can hack it by creating a whole load of boxes of certain widths, but this is very technical and not robust: if stuff changes, I need to change some box-sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `align` inside of `gather`. There is however the old issue with `\label` (see [Labels and nesting gather and align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412261/82917)). The workaround proposed there does not seem to work with more than one label, so I try here another version. I must admit, however, that I haven't tested it as thoroughly as I'd feel comfortable with.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}% twocolumn for smaller snapshot

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\math@cr@@@align}{\cr}{\global\let\df@label\@empty\cr}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    A = B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I \label{a} \\
\begin{align}
    X &\le 2 \label{b} \\
    Y &\le 123 \label{c}
\end{align}
\\
A = B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I \label{d}\\
\begin{aligned}
    X &\le 2 \\
    Y &\le 123123
\end{aligned}\label{e}
\end{gather}
The five above: \eqref{a}, \eqref{b}, \eqref{c}, \eqref{d}, \eqref{e}.
%
% The following lines are only to check that nothing weird is going on.
%
The following ones: \eqref{test1}, \eqref{test2}.
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a&=b \label{test1} \\
c&=d \label{test2} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Oh wow! I always use `align` as a top-level environment and `aligned` inside. Now you mention this, though, I'm pretty sure someone else a similar thing elsewhere (`<–` strong statement `=P`). Thanks!

Comment: Ooh, I was a bit too fast accepting. I see that you didn't attach labels, but I did say that I wanted to label them—this is for cross-referencing. I get an error, saying that the two 'inner' labels—the ones inside the `align`—"will be lost". However, if I ignore this warning and use `\eqref` to reference them, it prints out what I desire... :/

Comment: @SamOT Oooh, that's an old issue, I thought it had been fixed... See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412261/82917

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is a >4yr old issue and, as you say, the use of `align` inside `gather`. The fix egreg suggests in "August 2019 update" doesn't seem to work either. If you add `\label{l3}` to equation 3, then it says that it will lose `\label{l2}`

Comment: @SamOT I've come up with another workaround for the labels. It seems to work, but I should do a bit more testing.

Comment: Thank you for this! This looks like it works well enough that it deserves an acceptance. The safest solution seems to be "find a way of typesetting your document so that you don't need this". However, I'm never that keen on such solutions. If that was always people's response, then there wouldn't be any nice packages or anything!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple `align`?

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    A = B + C + D & + E + F + G + H + I
    \\
        X &\le 2 \\
        Y &\le 123123
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first row isn't centred with respect to the rest then, unfortunately :(

Comment: It is (approximately) if you take into account the last equation, which is longer than the second one.

Comment: Sure, it is approximately centred. I would rather it be actually centred, though. For one, if I change stuff, I want it to automatically re-centre. I presumed that it would be fairly simple, but it seems that this 4yr-old bug hasn't been fixed, unfortunately